# React Next.js useEffect when the first render of the page is not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am developing with React. I have different pages. But I want all my filters to be cleared except when going to the 'Football' page. When I go to a page other than the Football page and come back, my filters remain the same. But when I go back and forth for the second time, my filters are cleaned. I want my filters to be cleaned the first time. I want my filters to be cleared when the page is first rendered I request support

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.pathname !== '/dashboard/football') {
            localStorage.removeItem('filters');
        }
    }, [location.pathname]);
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filters'))) {
        general = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filters'))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the bug. Here is the solve this way.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const storedFilters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filters'));

    if (storedFilters && window.location.pathname !== '/dashboard/football') {
    }
    return () => {
        if (window.location.pathname !== '/dashboard/football') {
            localStorage.removeItem('filters');
        }
    };
}, []);
```